# Flask Rate-Limiting on two keys at once

Tags: python, flask, rate-limiting

I have the following rate limits:

```
@ip_limiter.limit("15/minute;150/day")
@user_limiter.limit("15/minute;150/day")
```

The problem with this setup, is the way I understand it, it effectively is just an IP rate limiter. The situation I'm trying to avoid is the following:

A person rapid-fires 15 requests, then switches IP addresses and sends 15 more from the same account, then switches IP addresses again...

If I switch it to the following:

```
@ip_limiter.limit("15/minute;150/day")
@user_limiter.limit("15/minute;150/day")
```

then I get the opposite problem - someone from one IP can rapid-fire 15 requests from a single account (one IP address), then switch accounts and rapid-fire 15 more. I want to force them to have to switch BOTH the IP address AND the account, since accounts are fairly easy to spin-up.

To sum it up, I basically need an either-or rate limiting technique.

One method I've seen that doesn't seem to solve the problem is making the lookup key a combination of IP and user. The problem with that is they can switch IP's OR users and the key changes just as easily. I'm looking for more of a "increment both IP and user limit counts, check if either IP or user limit has been reached, and block on either-or" solution.

I've played around with something along the lines of this pseudocode but I can't get the exact code right.

```
limit_reached = False
try: 
  ip_limiter.check()
except:
  limit_reached = True
try:
  user_limiter.check()
except:
  limit_reach = True
if limit_reached:
  return (limit reached message with limit reached error code)
```